# Installing GPSBabel on CentOS 5 x86_64

Tags: installation, centos5, packages

Well first let me say I have no clue about doing anything on my server, I ask my host to do all installs for me.

I run a website where users store latitude and longitude coordinates in my database. I would like them to be able to download these waypoints to their gps units.

I found a program called GPSBabel that allows this to be done. http://www.gpsbabel.org/

I want to be able to control GPSBabel from PHP using exec() or something along those lines.

The problem is that the linux version of the program is a source file and they don't want to build or install it without some source of instructions. Does anyone have experience with installing this? Perhaps know someone that has and that can lead me in the right direction?

Any help would be hugely appreciated. I'm pretty much stuck without getting this to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, I [built a package for you](http://obliquity.seas.harvard.edu/~lars/rpms/5/x86_64/gpsbabel-1.4.2-6.el5.centos.x86_64.rpm).  This can be installed by running:

```
yum install gpsbabel-1.4.2-6.el5.centos.x86_64.rpm
```

`gpsbabel` is already packed for Fedora, which means that source RPMS are available.  A source RPM (or SRPM) is basically the source and a set of rules for building it; this is used to create binary RPM packages for installation on your servers.  Very often, source RPMS for Fedora will build trivially on CentOS.

Comment: I feel that I would be remiss if I did not note that that from a security perspective it is a bad idea to install binary packages from untrusted sources.

Comment: The link you supplied seems to be gone. Can you supply another one or tell us where we can find this rpm?